# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The external table is not in the expected format with ACE.OLEDB and Excel 12 Xml

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have a problem with **OleDb** connection, i don't know what it's the problem, I try different way to solve, but no one works.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Evans\Downloads\Cursos\doc.xlsx";
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;";
        OleDbConnection oleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]", oleDbCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
```

Also I try it without **Xml**

Comment: Open sheet1 and check if it is a Worksheet.  Could be picture. Also set command type : cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect

Comment: I think I found the problem, the file it was protected so i need to enable the edit and with the file open i need to execute the program and works, but that file i donwload it from a plataform so i don't know if i need to do that steps every time i try to import it